# Leaving UK for holiday after thesis submission

Tags: visa

I’m planning to submit my final PhD thesis and then go back home for holiday. Then, I’ll back for my VIVA. The expected date of my viva is 1 March 2018 and my Tier 4 visa is valid till Sep 2018.

Is it ok that I leave the UK after my thesis submission and go back once my viva date is set?

Comment: As long as you are not missing anything at your university it shouldn't be a problem. You might want to carry some paperwork indicating that you are a PhD student since it would look odd for an _undergraduate_ to be away in term time.

Comment: Make sure you're still enrolled at the university. I seem to remember a question from someone in the same situation who had trouble re-entering because he was technically not enrolled.